# When running an MFC application is there a way to output to a "console"?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2017, mfc

I'm used to developing with C++ in Qt Creator, much more so than Visual Studio. In the former, you can do something like this

```
qDebug()<< my_trace_string;
```

to output my_trace_string to a "console" which can be handy so that you can see what is going on.
I wondered if there is a Visual Studio window to which an application can easily write, independently of the dialogs and controls. This is complementary to the use of the debugger. It leaves a visual trace for example.

Comment: It depends if you are including windows.h to make a windows executable or if you are making other kinds of projects.  For windows executables what about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw

Comment: In the MFC program, you can also use the [TRACE macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/mfc-debugging-techniques?view=vs-2019#BKMK_The_TRACE_macro) to output debugging information.The TRACE macro can output debugging information to the Output window during debugging.

Answer (score 3):

`OutputDebugString()` from `debuapi.h` (just `#include <windows.h>`) is your friend. I usually wrap it up into a function like this (use **A** suffix for ASCII or **W** suffix for for UNICODE):

```
void dbgMsg(PCWSTR _format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _format);

    WCHAR msg[MAX_PATH];

    if(SUCCEEDED(StringCbVPrintfW(msg, sizeof(msg), _format, args))){
        OutputDebugStringW(msg);
    }
}
```

That will output into `Output` window in IDE (next to `Call stack`, `Error List` and others)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio when working on GUI programs the usual method for such is to use the _RPTX (where X is the number of varadic parameters) macros which when report type is _CRT_WARN print to the Output window within VS itself rather than use an external console window.

For example:

```
_RPT1(_CRT_WARN, __FUNCTION__ ": hWnd: %#x\r\n", m_hWnd);
```

Personally I prefer using the following (custom) macros which do not take the report type (I simple use _CRT_WARN) and also do away with the need to know the number of vararg parameters and also the ability to take more than 4 vararg parameters (the limit with the default macros). The _RPT macros have simply never been updated to take advantage of the variadic macro capable preprocessor:

```
#if !defined(_RPTW)
#if defined(_DEBUG)
#define _RPTW(pszFmt, ...) _CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_WARN, NULL, __LINE__, NULL, (pszFmt), __VA_ARGS__)
#define _RPTWF(dest, fmt, ...) _CrtDbgReportW((dest), _T(__FILE__), __LINE__, NULL, (pszFmt), __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define _RPTW(pszFmt, ...)
#define _RPTWF(dest, pszFmt)
#endif
#endif // #if !defined(_RPTW)

#if !defined(_RPTA)
#if defined(_DEBUG)
#define _RPTA(pszFmt, ...) _CrtDbgReport(_CRT_WARN, NULL, __LINE__, NULL, (pszFmt), __VA_ARGS__)
#define _RPTAF(dest, fmt, ...) _CrtDbgReport((dest), __FILE__, __LINE__, NULL, (pszFmt), __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define _RPTA(pszFmt, ...)
#define _RPTAF(dest, pszFmt)
#endif
#endif // #if !defined(_RPTA)

#if !defined(_RPTT)
#if defined(_UNICODE)
#define _RPTT _RPTW
#define _RPTTF _RPTWF
#else
#define _RPTT _RPTA
#define _RPTTF _RPTAF
#endif
#endif // #if !defined(_RPTT)
```

Using the custom macros the original example becomes:

```
_RPTA(__FUNCTION__ ": hWnd: %#x\r\n", m_hWnd);
```

The original way does have the benefit of taking the report type as a parameter, using that output can be redirected to a window (as _ASSERT does), the output window (the default with _CRT_WARN) or to a trace file (requires calling _CrtSetReportMode and _CrtSetReportFile).

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you could try to call the [`AllocConsole` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) to create a Console for your process.
2. Send your output to the console via [`_cprintf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/cprintf-cprintf-l-cwprintf-cwprintf-l?view=vs-2019)And don't forget to #include  wherever you use `_cprintf()`
3. If you need to close the console output, call [`FreeConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole);

For more details you could refer to [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612/Creating-a-Console-for-Your-MFC-Apps-Debug-Output)

Comment: That looks interesting because a dedicated output console will be free of the clutter of less interesting messages coming from the application.